# How do you tell if a pipe opened process has terminated?

Tags: perl, file-io, pipe, ipc

Assuming a handle created with the following code:

```
use IO::File;

my $fh = IO::File->new;

my $pid = $fh->open('some_long_running_proc |') or die $!;

$fh->autoflush(1);
$fh->blocking(0);
```

and then read with a loop like this:

```
while (some_condition_here) {
    my @lines = $fh->getlines;
    ...
    sleep 1;
}
```

What do I put as `some_condition_here` that will return false if the process on the other end of the pipe has terminated?

Testing for `$fh->eof` will not work since the process could still be running without printing any new lines.  Testing for `$fh->opened` doesn't seem to do anything useful.

Currently I am using `$pid =! waitpid($pid, WNOHANG)` which seems to work in POSIX compliant environments.  Is this the best way?  What about on Windows?

Comment: Does `$fh->blocking(0)` even work on Windows? I though that there was [some heavy wizardry](http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=92881) involved in getting non-blocking I/O to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On using `select`,

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use IO::Select qw( );

sub process_msg {
    my ($client, $msg) = @_;
    chomp $msg;
    print "$client->{id} said '$msg'\n";
    return 1;  # Return false to close the handle.
}

my $select = IO::Select->new();
my %clients;

for (...) {
    my $fh = ...;
    $clients{fileno($fh)} = {
        id  => '...'
        buf => '',
        # ...
    };

    $select->add($fh);
}

while (my @ready = $select->can_read) {
    for my $fh (@ready) {
        my $client = $clients{ fileno($fh) };
        our $buf; local *buf = \( $client->{buf} );

        my $rv = sysread($fh, $buf, 64*1024, length($buf));
        if (!$rv) {
            if (defined($rv)) {
                print "[$client->{id} ended]\n";
            } else {
                print "[Error reading from $client->{id}: $!]\n";
            }

            print "[Incomplete message received from $client->{id}]\n"
                if length($buf);

            delete $clients{ fileno($fh) };
            $select->remove($fh);
            next;
        }

        while ($buf =~ s/^(.*\n)//) {
            if (!process_msg($client, "$1")) {
                print "[Dropping $client->{id}]\n";
                delete $clients{ fileno($fh) };
                $select->remove($fh);
                last;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with waiting for an actual EOF?

```
while (<$fh>) {
    ...
    sleep 1;
}
```

You've set the handle for non-blocking reads, so it should just do the right thing. Indeed, given your example, you don't even need to set non-blocking and can get rid of the sleep.

Are there other things that you want to do while waiting on `some_long_running_proc`? If so, `select` is probably in your future.

Comment: The example I gave is overly simplified, there are multiple filehandles opened, and the while loop polls all of them, so I can't have it block on any individual handle.

Comment: @Eric Strom, `select` will tell you what handles need servicing, and that includes those that have been closed. Follow up with a `sysread` to check for EOF. I recommend using [IO::Select] instead of using `select` directly.

Answer (score 2):

There a number of options.

- [`readline`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readline.html) aka `<$fh>` will return false on eof (or error).
- [`eof`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eof.html) will return true on eof.
- [`read`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/read.html) (with block size > 0) will return defined and zero on eof.
- [`sysread`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sysread.html) (with block size > 0) will return defined and zero on eof.

You can use [`select`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IO%3a%3aSelect) or make the handle non-blocking before any of the above to check without blocking.

Comment: eof just tells you that there is not currently any more input to be read. It doesn't tell you whether the other end of the pipe might give you some more input later.

Comment: @mob, You are mistaken. If the handle's buffer isn't empty, `eof` returns true. If the handle's buffer is empty, `eof` performs a `read` and returns true when the `read` returns true.

Comment: @mob, You should verify your claims before contradicting someone.

Comment: @mob, `perl -MData::Dumper -e'open(my $fh, "cat|") or die; print(Dumper(eof($fh)));'`

Comment: I stand by my claim that `eof` can be true while the other end of the pipe is still active and can later become false. e.g. `use IO::Handle;pipe $R,$W;$W->autoflush(1); $R->blocking(0);if(!fork()){for(1..5){sleep$_;print $W "$_\n"}exit}print"eof=",$R->eof;sleep 2;print"\neof=",$R->eof`

Comment: @mob, That's a different claim. (You previously said it was "just a check", and I showed that was false.) And yes, `eof` will return true when not eof in that circumstance when one specifically asks it to do so as you did.

Comment: @mob, Note that your example doesn't contradict what I said, since `read` did return an error (`EAGAIN`).

Comment: Nothing you said was wrong. I downvoted this answer because it was not useful for the specific problem the OP is having (except maybe the part about `select`). The OP specifically mentioned testing `eof` and why it wasn't going to help him.

Answer (score 1):

You use select() to ascertain whether there is any data, or an exceptional condition such as a close.

Personally I prefer to use IO::Multiplex, especially where you're multiplexing input from several different descriptors, but that may not apply in this case.